# What is the range of Dr. Strange's portal spell?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

In the MCU, is it ever stated how far within our own universe Dr. Strange can travel with a single portal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In the MCU, is it ever stated how far within our own universe Dr. Strange can travel with a single portal?

There is no limitation to how far a sling ring can transport the user, Dr. Strange included.

From *[Dr. Strange (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1211837/)*:

> MORDO: Mastery of the sling ring is essential to the mystic arts. **They allow us to travel throughout the multiverse.** All you need to do is focus. Visualize. See the destination in your mind. .. Imagine every detail. The clearer the picture, the quicker, and easier, the gateway will come.

So, not only can Dr. Strange travel anywhere within this universe, but also to other universes, and anywhere within them too (as long as he can visualize it).

Comment: considering your answer here, would you care to comment/answer on [my question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88435/why-didnt-dr-strange-use-his-sling-ring-to-escape-thanos)... any insights would be appreciated!