# Why doesn't Dr. Strange fight by opening portals in front of moving body parts and severing them

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe

Why doesn't Dr. Strange fight people by opening portals in front of moving body parts (punched fists, running legs, jumping heads) and then closing the portals?

In fact, he can even open a portal anywhere, move it around his target, and close it.

It seems to me this would be so efficient.

[Similar question asking about Thanos' hand specifically](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88474/why-didnt-dr-strange-create-a-portal-to-cut-off-thanos-hand), top answers suggest it's too difficult.

I don't care about Thanos-specific situations, I want to know why Strange doesn't employ it in *all* his fights. Why is this not something he practises?

Comment: *"I don't care about MCU answers only"* - Sorry, but we do. If you want general comic explanations without any relation to the films, you might be better served on [scifi.se]. Besides that, not believing what the answers to the duplicate question say doesn't automatically make this question not a duplicate.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson ta-da